# How to get call information in my app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there any possibility to get call information in my app ?

a simple scenario :

- i received a call
- open the app
- How can i get the call information in may app (phone number, name) ?

Comment: `io` = `Input/Output`, I assume your tag meant `iOS`? It would also help what language you are referring to, i.e `Swift`/`Objective-C` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Its not possible to get the Call Information. Its private API.